# ES6 React server-side rendering, how to import a React Component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm transpiling ES6 to ES5.

1. BabelJS for the NodeJS Express server files and server-side rendering output to a directory build/server/.
2. Browserify + babelify for the ReactComponents output to a build/client/bundle.js file

When trying to import a React Component from build/client/bundle.js to a build/server/ file the app crashes because I'm importing an untranspiled ReactComponent.

How could I import the ReactComponent without duplicating the code in the server (re-using the code from the client/bundle.js)?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few solutions:

- Your server code doesn't need to be pre-compiled. If you run it with [`babel-node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node), it will be compiled on-the-fly.
- You could bundle your server code. I don't know any resource on how to do it with browserify, but [here's a very good resource](https://github.com/jlongster/backend-with-webpack) to get started with webpack for your backend.
- You could build your client code alongside your server code.